# JIRA Historic Data with Structure Plugin

Tags: powerbi, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

i want to connect JIRA to Power BI for analyzing many JIRA projects. We use the JIRA strucutre Plugin.

My goal is to have the peristed, histroic data from the JIRA issues. A example is to analyze the issues change in Power BI.

Has anyone an idea, how to get this data? Is there a way to use the structe plugin API for this? Or the classic JIRA API?

Thanks for the help!

I tried to use the structre plugin API, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There is a Jira API and you need to graph the items over time by their create date. For this you'll need to use a DAX function. So for example if you loaded all your issues into a table called Load projects then you would need to create a measure in DAX and use this in an Area chart on the y-axis with 'Date Updated' on the x-axis

```
BugRunningTotalAll =  
CALCULATE(

    SUMX(LoadProjects, 1), // Use 1 here to count each bug

    FILTER(

             ALLSELECTED(LoadProjects),

             LoadProjects[DateCreated] <= MAX(LoadProjects[Updated]) && 
             LoadProjects[IssueType] = "Bug"
    )

)
```

Hope this helps

I've developed a Power BI template which does exactly this(and alot more) and it's possible to do graphs like this along with project burnups etc (see screenshot below). Template is available here -https://payhip.com/b/q65WX